# IBindingList change notification

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I am trying to create a program (simple grid - with specialized output) that displays data from an IBindingList data source.  I can display the data just fine, but I also want to be able to let the user edit the data in, say in a TextBox that is separate from the grid. My problem is that I am unclear as to how to accomplish the "automatic" updating of the data between the two elements (my grid and the editable textbox).

The list's ListChanged event, I believe, will tell me when the list itself has changed, but I need the grid to know when the actual data in the list has changed. The only thing I have stumbled upon to tell me when a change external to the grid has occurred is to hook onto the BindingManagerBase.Bindings[0].Parse event.  Not that a user would do this, but if the user has established several textboxes that are all bound to the same field, I think I would have to loop through each BindingManagerBase.Binding entry and hook it?

I am presuming I am not doing this correctly, and there is a more generalized way to accomplish this. I would GREATLY appreciate some direction from anyone who is more familiar with what I am attempting to accomplish.

Thanks in advance,
-Matt

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at at [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  Implement it on the class that is stored in your BindingList to notify said BindingList when properties on an item change.

If you've implemented IBindingList yourself you'll need to do a little more work to hook up to the events for each item in your list, but the provided BindingList will pick up on these events automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have already tried that, and that works just fine. But what I am confused about, is that other applications (like MS DataGridView, etal) operate "correctly" without the class having INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on the class.  Might you have an idea how they accomplish this?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears DGV is just getting and setting the value on every row/cell they encounter from the binding source.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the generic [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and notify the edit using ResetItem